# How to display an "image-not-found" image in case of v-img loading errors

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Look at this code pen for a simple vuetify setup.

https://codepen.io/khoulaiz/pen/gObJPxO?editors=1010

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-col v-for="i in images" :key="i" cols="4">
              <v-img max-height="150" max-width="150" :src="i" @error="errorHandler"/>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<scritp>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data: () => ({
      images: [
        "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
        "https://via.placeholder.com/doesnotexist",
        "https://via.placeholder.com/152"
      ]
    }),
    methods: {
      errorHandler(url) {
        images[1] = "https://via.placeholder.com/151"
        this.$forceUpdate()
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

The middle image will fail to load. I have an error handler, in which I would like to replace the src attribute of the failing image with a working image and in which I would like to force a reload of the image.

I am able to replace the src of the failing image, but I fail in all my attempts to force a reload of the v-img.

Why on earth do I not get a reference to the v-img that fails to load? Instead I get the failing url, which doesn't help me to locate the failing element. :-(

Please tell me, how I can force the second image to show the backup image. Please note that the image should be part of a v-for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access your images with
`this.`

Changing your `errorHandler` to the following should do the trick

```
errorHandler(url) {
  this.images[1] = "https://via.placeholder.com/151"
  this.$forceUpdate()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is our v-img: for dynamic loop through

```
<v-img 
      max-height="100%" 
     max-width="100%"
   :alt="item.name"
   :src="item.image ? item.image: require('~/assets/images/img-placeholder.jpg')"
            @error="onImageError()" 
          >
          </v-img>
```

here is error handler:

```
 methods: {
onImageError($event) {
   event.target.src = require('~/assets/images/img-placeholder.jpg');
},
```

}

Hope ! it helps you , must use $event

for better image handling you can do with backend image url(in case of image not found),with any Library(package) or default value(in database)

and For Professional Approach You can also use third party S3 cloud bucket service and generate presigned urls for all types of files.

Thank You, Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ref` so you can access your html object easily . Like below

```
 <v-col v-for="i in images" :key="i" cols="4">
          <v-img max-height="150" max-width="150" :src="i" :ref="'img_' + i" @error="errorHandler(i)"/>
 </v-col>
```

You need to set unique refs and pass that unique ref to errorHandler param.

From your errorHandler , you can take that param and retrieve image object dom by ref that set new src

```
errorHandler(i) {
    this.$refs['img_' + i][0].src = "https://via.placeholder.com/151"
}
```

Comment: I know, thank you. But the problem is not the reference or the update of the src attribute. The problem is the refresh of the image when the loading did not work. I am not able to do a forced update or to trigger otherwise the display of the updated image. Try yourself to change the code pen so that the image is displayed after the error occurred.

Comment: This was not my problem, but your solution helped me with another problem I had, so thanks, your solution helped me to solve a different riddle 